# Showing joined list connections in search results hover

Tags: document-library, search-results, display-template, search-box

I have searched for this but haven't found any examples (maybe it's my searching abilities) but I am hoping to solve the following problem in SharePoint 2013.

I am trying to replace a document library that has a connection (linked/joined) documents from another library filtered by a value.

I would like to use a search box and search results box and ideally have the linked documents show up in the search hover i.e. modify the search display template to show the connected documents.

I am not really sure where to start in order to do this and was wondering if anyone had done something similar or had any examples?

The attached image is what I want to do. The top part (LinkListMaster and ChildList) are setup and working, but I want the user to be able to search in the box and have the "ChildList" items come up in the hover display template.

Thanks very much for any help.
Roy

[image: See image below]